# Problem Installing Ros Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

Here is the error message that I have:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

This is what I get when I explore each of these dependency issues

ros-indigo-cpp-common : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.2 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-all-dev but it is not installable
Depends: libconsole-bridge-dev but it is not installable

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209597/problem-installing-ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-14.04.2/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2015-05-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned in [ROS Installation Guide for Ubuntu](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation-1), you need to install some dependencies manually for **14.04.2** . Quoting from the page:

> If you are using Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.2 and experience dependency issues during the ROS installation, you may have to install some additional system dependencies. **(Do not install these packages if you are using 14.04, it will destroy your X server)**

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic libxatracker-dev-lts-utopic libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgbm-dev-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
```

> Alternatively, try installing just this to fix dependency issues: **(Do not install the above packages if you are using 14.04, it will destroy your X server)**

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
```

> For more information on this issue see this [answers.ros.org thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/203610/ubuntu-14042-unmet-dependencies/) or this [launchpad issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa-lts-utopic/+bug/1424059)

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2015-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [juwinkler](https://answers.ros.org/users/24172/juwinkler/) on 2015-10-01**:
When trying to do this, terminal prints out that each of the packages could not be found.
Why does't it find them?

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-09-15**:
I'm using 14.04.5 and this doesn't work. It gives me similar "but it is not going to be installed" errors.